# Sentiment analysis - Pattern NLP

Tags: matplotlib, nlp, nltk

Trying to create a Subject Object polarity plot using pattern.

```
from pattern.en import parse,sentiment
print sentiment('The movie attempts to be surreal by incorporating various time paradoxes')

(0.125, 0.75)

from pattern.en import sentiment
print sentiment("He is good.") 

(0.7, 0.6000000000000001)

from pattern.en import sentiment
print sentiment("The movie attempts to be surreal by incorporating various time paradoxes. He is good.") 

(0.31666666666666665, 0.7000000000000001)
```

From what I understand is that the analysis calculates polarity for both the sentences and returns a normalized value. IS it possible for it to calculate score and return line by line, something like this

```
from pattern.en import sentiment
print sentiment("The movie attempts to be surreal by incorporating various time paradoxes. He is good.") 

(0.125, 0.75)
(0.7, 0.6000000000000001)
```

Part two: I want this series of x1,y1 value to be mapped to a scatter plot using numpy and amtplotlib. Is it possible?

With your code as guidance i tried to improve upon existing code by adding modality value. but i face

**Edit 1**

```
for sentence in sentences:
        modality(sentence)
    #mind the difference for the last sentence, which contains two dots.         
    for sentence in complete_text.split("."):
        modality(sentence)
    b = np.array([ modality(sentence) for sentence in complete_text.split(".") ])
    print "Modality: ", b[:,0]
```

Output error

```
print "Modality: ", b[:,0]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I am trying to change the marker symbol based on modality range which i am able to achieve while hard-coding the value. Trying extend your approach to modality of many sentences.

**Edit 2**

The graph is looking good but one important feature is not there. I need to click the marker point and want to return that particular sentence for which the click is made so to analyze those particular sentence of choice.Narrowed in to onclick (event) to return the sentence.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
def onclick(event):
    print('button=%d,' %(event.button))
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Unsure how to connect call sentence for that particular marker? This completes the last missing piece in my attempt at polarity analysis.

**Edit 3**

I am quite fixated with using red for negative sentiment and green for positive and markers for four types of modalities. I amended your code fit the need with the following function

```
print "polarities: ", a[:,0]
print "subjectivities: ", a[:,1]
print "modalities: ", a[:,2]
s = np.array(a[:,2])
r = np.array(a[:,1])
############ Plotting ############
def markers(s):
    if s > "0.5" and s< "1":
        return 'o'
    elif s > "0" or s < ".5":
        return 'x'
    elif s > "-.5" or s < "0":
        return 'v'
    else:
        return '^'

def colors(r):
    if r > "0" and r < "1":
        return "g"
    elif r < "0" or r > "-1":
        return "r"
    else:
        return "r"

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1], marker = markers(s), color= colors(r), s=100, picker=5)
```

But the graph returns x mark in red for all the variation. I am not sure why?

**Edit 4 :**

```
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter (p[(p>0.0)&(p<=1)&(m>0.5)&(m<=1)], s[(p>0.0)&(p<=1)&(m>0.5)&(m<=1)], marker = "o", color= 'g', s=100, picker=5)
ax.scatter (p[(p>0.0)&(p<=1)&(m>0.0)&(m<=0.5)], s[(p>0.0)&(p<=1)&(m>0.0)&(m<=0.5)], marker = "v", color= 'g', s=100, picker=5)


ax.scatter (p[(p>0.0)&(p<=1)&(m>-0.5)&(m<=0.0)], s[(p>0.0)&(p<=1)&(m>-0.5)&(m<=0.0)], marker = "s", color= 'g', s=100, picker=5)
ax.scatter (p[(p>0.0)&(p<=1)&(m>=-1.0)&(m<=-0.5)], s[(p>0.0)&(p<=1)&(m>=-1.0)&(m<=-0.5)], marker = "x", color= 'g', s=100, picker=5)
ax.scatter (p[(p>=-1.0)&(p<=0)&(m>0.5)&(m<=1)], s[(p>=-1.0)&(p<=0)&(m>0.5)&(m<=1)], marker = "o", color= 'r', s=100, picker=5)
ax.scatter (p[(p>=-1.0)&(p<=0)&(m>0.0)&(m<=0.5)], s[(p>=-1.0)&(p<=0)&(m>0.0)&(m<=0.5)], marker = "v", color= 'r', s=100, picker=5)
ax.scatter (p[(p>=-1.0)&(p<=0)&(m>-0.5)&(m<=0.0)], s[(p>=-1.0)&(p<=0)&(m>-0.5)&(m<=0.0)], marker = "s", color= 'r', s=100, picker=5)
ax.scatter (p[(p>=-1.0)&(p<=0)&(m>=-1.0)&(m<=-0.5)], s[(p>=-1.0)&(p<=0)&(m>=-1.0)&(m<=-0.5)], marker = "x", color= 'r', s=100, picker=5)

ax.set_xlabel("polarity")
ax.set_ylabel("subjectivity")
def onpick(event):
    index = event.ind
    for i in index:
        print i, sentences[i]
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

Unsure why def on pick doesn't give the relevant sentence but always the first sentence.

Comment: You shouldn't edit questions by deleting the main part of it. How are others now supposed to understand the issue?

Comment: Tried to consolidate the question to make it terse. Advice taken. Lucky to find the missing part.

Comment: Consolidation would be helpful, yes. But you shouldn't destroy the structure of edits, otherwise no one can follow anymore. Now, see edit 4 in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is an answer to the initial question.*

What defines your line in this case? 
If we can assume that the dot separates sentences, then we might use it to split the text `text.split(".")` into a list. Then it is possible to calculate the sentiment values for each item by

```
for sentence in complete_text.split("."):
    print sentiment(sentence)
```

See this code for a working example as well as how plotting would work.

```
from pattern.en import parse,sentiment

sentences = ["In fact, I'm not convinced that blue is a color.", 
             "The car is blue.",
             "Precisely speaking, no random opinion is allowed.",
             "Democracy is dead. Long live the king."]

complete_text = " ".join(sentences)


for sentence in sentences:
    print sentiment(sentence)

#mind the difference for the last sentence, which contains two dots.         
for sentence in complete_text.split("."):
    print sentiment(sentence)


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([ sentiment(sentence) for sentence in complete_text.split(".") ])

print "polarities: ", a[:,0]
print "subjectivities: ", a[:,1]

############ Plotting ############
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1], marker="s", linestyle="")
ax.set_xlabel("polarity")
ax.set_ylabel("subjectivity")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Exactly solves the problem. Although I use nltk sentence tokenizer to parse a paragraph and call it to sentences in your code. Works well.

Comment: `sentiment()` returns a tuple `(polarity, subjectivity)` such that the resulting numpy array is two dimensional (polarity in first column, subjectivity in second). In contrast to that, `modality()` returns a single value. Therefore the resulting array is one-dimensional and you just need to use it: `print "Modality: ", b`

Comment: Yes, does solve the issue. As one last add on question. Please see edit2.

Answer (score 3):

*This is an answer to the initial question and its Edit2. For an answer to Edit4 see bottom.*

I'm adding another answer to solve the question raised in Edit2. 
You didn't say, what you mean by "return the sentence", so I have to guess that you want to have it printed to the console. This is the code that would do that

```
from pattern.en import sentiment, modality

sentences0 = ["In fact, I'm not convinced that blue is a color.", 
             "The car is blue.",
             "Precisely speaking, no random opinion is allowed.",
             "Democracy is dead. Long live the king."]

complete_text = " ".join(sentences0)
sentences = complete_text.split(".")[:-1]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([ sentiment(sentence) for sentence in sentences ])
b = np.array([ modality(sentence) for sentence in sentences  ])

a = np.append(a, np.array([b]).T, axis=1)


print "polarities: ", a[:,0]
print "subjectivities: ", a[:,1]
print "modalities: ", a[:,2]


############ Plotting ############
def colors(x):
    return [(1-xi,0., xi) for xi in x]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1], marker="s", color=colors(a[:,2]), s=100, picker=5)
ax.set_xlabel("polarity")
ax.set_ylabel("subjectivity")
def onpick(event):
    index = event.ind
    for i in index:
        print i, sentences[i]

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

**Edit4**

The problem is that the returned indizes are those of the conditionned array, while `sentences` is not conditioned. 
Here is a program that should hopefully do what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sentences = ["Sentence0", "Sentence1", "Sentence2", "Sentence3", "Sentence4", "Sentence5"]
p = np.array( [ 0. ,  0.2 ,  -0.3 ,  0.2, 0., 0.2] )
s = np.array( [ 0.1,  0.,   0.,   0.3 , 0.1, 0.] )
m = np.array( [ 1.,   -0.25,  1. ,  -0.6, 0.2,-0.25   ] )


colors = np.array([(0.8*(1-x), 0.7*x, 0) for x in np.ceil(p)])

cond = [(m>0.5)&(m<=1), (m>0.0)&(m<=0.5), (m>-0.5)&(m<=0.0), (m>=-1.0)&(m<=-0.5) ]
markers = ["o", "v", "s", "x"]


fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

sc=[]
for i in range(len(cond)):
    sc0 = ax.scatter(p[cond[i]], s[cond[i]], marker = markers[i], color= colors[cond[i]], s=100, picker=5)
    sc.append(sc0)

ax.set_xlabel("polarity")
ax.set_ylabel("subjectivity")

def onpick(event):
    index = event.ind
    artist = event.artist
    print len(index)
    for i in index:
        try:
            which = sc.index(artist)
            print i, sentences[int(np.arange(len(p))[cond[which]][i])]
        except:
            #raise
            print "no sentence found"

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks exactly does what it must,but for one small change that I mentioned in edit3.

Comment: I think we're out of the scope of the question by now. The problem you're having in Edit3 is that you're comparing one apple to a bunch of oranges or vice versa. You may want to have a look at this one: [link](http://i.imgur.com/WRuJV6r.png)

Comment: I understand the issue now.

Comment: Reply to Edit 4 solves the whole issue. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from pattern.en import sentiment,modality
    from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
    sentences = ["In fact, I'm not convinced that blue is a color.", 
                 "The car is blue.",
                 "Precisely speaking, no random opinion is allowed.",
                 "Democracy is dead. Long live the king."]
    complete_text = " ".join(sentences)
    for sentence in sentences:
        sentiment(sentence)    
    a = np.array([ sentiment(sentence) for sentence in complete_text.split(".") ])
    for sentence in sentences:
        modality(sentence)
    b = np.array([ modality(sentence) for sentence in complete_text.split(".") ])
    print "polarities: ", a[:,0]
    print "subjectivities: ", a[:,1]
    print "Modality: ", b
    print
    (x1) = a[:,0]
    (y1) = a[:,1]
    (z1) = b
    x = np.array([x1])
    y = np.array([y1])
    z = np.array([z1])
    i_opt1 = np.where((x >= 0) & (0.5 < z) & (z <= 1))
    i_opt2 = np.where((x >= 0) & (0 < z) & (z <= 0.5))  
    i_opt3 = np.where((x >= 0) & (-0.5 < z) & (z <= 0)) 
    i_opt4 = np.where((x >= 0) & (-1 < z) & (z <= -0.5))  
    i_opt5 = np.where((x < 0) &(0.5 < z) & (z <= 1))  
    i_opt6 = np.where((x < 0) &(0 < z) & (z <= 0.5))  
    i_opt7 = np.where((x < 0) &(-0.5 < z) & (z <= 0))  
    i_opt8 = np.where((x < 0) &(-1 < z) & (z <= -0.5))
    plt.scatter(x[i_opt1], y[i_opt1], label='Indicative', color='g', s=25, marker="o")
    plt.scatter(x[i_opt2], y[i_opt2], label='Imperative', color='g', s=25, marker="x")
    plt.scatter(x[i_opt3], y[i_opt3], label='Conditional', color='g', s=25, marker="^")
    plt.scatter(x[i_opt4], y[i_opt4], label='Subjunctive', color='g', s=25, marker="v")
    plt.scatter(x[i_opt5], y[i_opt5], color='r', s=25, marker="o")
    plt.scatter(x[i_opt6], y[i_opt6], color='r', s=25, marker="x")
    plt.scatter(x[i_opt7], y[i_opt7], color='r', s=25, marker="^")
    plt.scatter(x[i_opt8], y[i_opt8], color='r', s=25, marker="v")
    plt.xlabel('Sentiment polarity: negative -> positive')
    plt.ylabel('Subjectivity: objective -> subjective')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Although a round-about way of achieving the result; thought it would be helpful to somebody. But, if some one could get to work "def on click" on this ,that would be nice.